# Did I get the calculation right? (probability)

Tags: probability

$4$ random people meet. What is the probability of at least $2$ of them being born on a Monday? I hardly have any intuition for probabilities..
But here is my intuitive approach, can you please check if it is correct?
$P(X > 1)=P(X=2)+P(X=3)+P(X=4)=\binom{4}{2}({1 \over 7^2}\cdot{6^2\over 7^2}) +\binom{4}{1}({1\over 7^3} \cdot {6\over7})+{1\over7^4} \approx 0.10037$

**Edit:** Now I am wondering if I can just multiply the solution by $7$ if I am looking for the probability of at least $2$ of them being born on the same weekday?

Comment: Your solution is right.

Comment: How do I have to modify the calculation for at least $2$ of them being born on the same weekday?

Comment: I guess multiplaying by $7$ is not the right answer..

Comment: Don't multiply by $7$. Try something like ... The first person could be born on any of the $7$ days of the week, the second could be born on $6$, the third $5$ & the fourth on $4$ ... this will give us all four people born on different days ... we want exactly the opposite of this ... $1-\frac{7}{7} \frac{6}{7}\frac{5}{7}\frac{4}{7}$

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. Is there a simple way to calculate it without calculating the opposite? I never really know (yet) when I should calculate the opposite or not which makes it much easier sometimes as in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct! This is the standard way to approach the problem.